# Cannot upload picture because browser refreshes

Tags: browser, camera, chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android, stock-browser

When I try to upload a photo to most sites, my low-end phone (an LG Optimus F6) refreshes the page after I select the file, regardless of what browser I use. Chrome at least explicitly tells me that it could not complete the operation due to a lack of memory. This is true regardless of whether I use the camera to take a new photo, or whatever app I use to choose an existing photo.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is anyone aware of a workaround?

Comment: Does this happen if you try uploading files on a different website? If the issue happens only on a specific website, then it's a problem on that site not the browser or system, and you should report the problem to the site owner.

Answer (score 0):

I was have the same problem with my Motorola Fire XT311 from 2 years ago, but i tried [X-plore FM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en) to select the files and it's works great sometimes, try it and tell me the result!